# Question about login logs using "sudo su - username"?

Tags: linux, sudo, login, su

While doing my Linux training I found this curiosity:

If I do `"sudo su - username"` and log into that username account, it doesn't count as login when I do "finger username"

[image]

Take this image where "jonathan" it's me (current user) and alumne2 is another account I created to test basic commands on it.

**Why it doesn't show up the last logging (finger alumne2) if from jonathan I "log in" as `"sudo su - alumne2"`?**

Comment: Neither `sudo` nor `su` are login programs.  That's why they don't show up in the "last login" output; you're not _logging in_ as that user; you're assuming that user's identity... a different function, entirely.

Comment: So you access an account but don't log in? Can you explain me that in a solution? Thanks

Comment: Related: [Is there ever a good reason to run sudo su?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/218169)

Comment: Please, [don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways of gaining access to a user account; for example you may login on a console, or `ssh` to a server, or `ftp` to get files, or have a `cron` job or...

Not all of these methods are considered "login".

`sudo` and `su` are ways of assuming an account identity, but neither of these are considered login methods.

So if you do a `finger` or `last` or look at the `lastlogin` records then you may not see activity under that account being reported there.

You may only see it in things like `/var/log/auth.log` (exact file name will depend on your OS).

Comment: I tested that and you are right! For a moment I thought I discovered some flaw in security.

Answer (score 1):

As stated by Stephen Harris in the comments, `su` is not a login command. Rather, you are substituting your shells current identity with another one.

This is nicely explained in [OpenBSD's man page for su](https://man.openbsd.org/su.1).

> The su utility allows a user to run a shell with the user and group ID
> of another user without having to log out and in as that other user.
>
> By default, the environment is unmodified with the exception of
> LOGNAME, HOME, SHELL, and USER. HOME and SHELL are set to the target
> login's default values. LOGNAME and USER are set to the target login,
> unless the target login has a user ID of 0 and the -l flag was not
> specified, in which case it is unmodified. The invoked shell is the
> target login's. This is the traditional behavior of su.

Comment: It's an augmentation rather than a substitution, as the original account remains available.  http://jdebp.eu./FGA/dont-abuse-su-for-dropping-privileges.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info, I will take a look!